# .gitignore hiding appsettings.json index

Tags: git, gitignore

I am writing an API for Task Management.  I adjusted .gitignore and added ***/appsetting.json. It worked and I don't see appsettings.json on github repo. But I want something like that: appsettings.json will be seen on GitHub but it will not show my connection string. Are there any ways to do this?
I couldn't find any information about this.
Also when one of my friends pull repo. It will download appsettings.json but Connection String willl be shown like this "!!!!!!!"